# How to aggregate an abstract class?

Tags: java, abstract, aggregation

so I'm trying to implement an aggregation relation between two classes. But, I'm a sort of confused on how to implement it with an abstract class. 
Any advice?

Beverage.java

```
    public class Beverage {

        private Size size;
        private SizeFactor sizeCost;
        private String description; 

        public Beverage(){}

        public Size getSize(){
            return size;
        }

        public SizeFactor getSizeCost(){
            return sizeCost;
        }

        public String getDescription(){
            return description;
        }

        public void setSize(Size s){
            size = s;
        }

        public void setSizeCost(SizeFactor cost){
            sizeCost = cost;
        }

        public double cost(){
            return sizeCost.sizeCost(size);
        }

    }
```

BeverageWithIngredient.java

```
   public abstract class BeverageWithIngredient extends Beverage {

   private Beverage drink = new Beverage();

   public abstract String getDescription();
   public abstract double cost();

}
```

Basically, this is what I'm trying to do:

[image: UML]

Comment: You shouldn't use 'extends' for aggregation. This is supposed to be a 'has-a' relationship, not a 'is-a' relationship, is 'extends' implies. Read more here: http://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/aggregation/

Comment: there's nothing wrong mixing *has-a* and *is-a* relations. This diagram fulfills decorator pattern

Comment: The diagram above follows the decorator pattern as k0ner stated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to inject `Beverage` into `BeverageWithIngredient`

```
public abstract class BeverageWithIngredient extends Beverage {

   private Beverage drink;

   public BeverageWithIngredient(Beverage drink) {
       this.drink = drink;
   }

   public abstract String getDescription();
   public abstract double cost();
}
```